# How can I answer my own question?

Tags: support

I would like to answer, at least partially, my question [61785](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61785/is-it-right-that-the-fundamental-recurrence-of-an-arbitrary-continued-fraction-ca) of Sep 4.

At the moment it has no answers.

The difficulty is that the answer window is not displayed, at least to me.

Can someone explain it?

Added: I just have to click the "Answer your question" button, as commented by Theo Buehler.

Comment: Pretty much after posting it.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: So, now I cannot.

Comment: Don't you have a "Answer your question" button on the lower left of the window? [Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Whl.png).

Comment: @Theo: I do have. Thanks!

Comment: @Theo Buehler: Could you please post your comment as an answer, so that I could accept it?

Comment: Américo, it might be a better idea to practice with that button on this question, if Theo has no objection... :)

Comment: @J.M. Good idea. Done.

Comment: Sorry for not following up earlier, I was distracted. I'm all in favor of the exercise suggested by @J.M.

Comment: @Theo: after this exercise I think I will never forget how to do it. (I was afraid of beeing only able to answer my own question within a certain time frame.) Thanks once more!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just have to click the "Answer your question" button, as commented by Theo Buehler.

Comment: (and now after waiting for the requisite number of hours, you can also practice accepting your own answer! `:-)`)

Comment: @Willie Wong: Yes, I'll do that in two days.